# How do I turn off avahi-daemon on boot?

Tags: networking, dhclient

I just switched from Windows 8 to Ubuntu 13.04. I installed UFW GUI interface for the firewall. In the listening report it shows the something called dhclient and avahi-daemon running in a few ports.

I google both, but could not find a clear answer on if I need them and if not how do I turn them off. The only things I use my home computer for is the internet (Midori browser), steam and arduino.

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 7):

`stop avahi-daemon` - to stop the service

`cd /etc/init ; touch avahi-daemon.override ; echo "manual" > avahi-daemon.override` - to prevent it from initiating on reboot .

Comment: Pretty sure with `systemd` this would be `sudo systemctl stop avahi-daemon` and `sudo systemctl mask avahi-daemon` to disable beyond the next reboot (you can `disable` rather than `mask` but that is reset at boot I believe).