# How can I ensure a service is disabled on boot?

Tags: boot, command-line, services

For some reason I need to disable a system service on boot. In my case this is the Avahi Daemon. I just don't want it to start on boot.

In previous Ubuntu releases (e.g. 12.04) I could do

```
sudo update-rc.d avahi-daemon disable
```

However on 14.04 it shows

```
update-rc.d: warning:  start runlevel arguments (none) do not match avahi-daemon Default-Start values (2 3 4 5)
update-rc.d: warning:  stop runlevel arguments (none) do not match avahi-daemon Default-Stop values (0 1 6)
 System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/avahi-daemon do not exist.
```

And Avahi is started on boot. How can I disable this? I'm looking for a command line way of doing this.

And please care to explain what happened here? Some change in a recent Ubuntu release broke the use of `update-rc.d`? I suspect I'm missing something here.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/286049/202806

Comment: @AvinashRaj through OP want to disable an specific service, he scoped it in a more general variant.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ubuntu uses [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) instead of SysV Init to start services on boot. Thus some services don't have an SysV Init script but an Upstart job description file in `/etc/init/` (not `/etc/init.d/`). For those `update-rc.d` doesn't work.

Use

```
echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/avahi-daemon.override
```

to disable `avahi-daemon` starting at boot. Replace `avahi-daemon` with whatever service you like to stop.

See [Upstart Intro, Cookbook and Best Practises](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) for more about how to work with Upstart.

Comment: This will change when Ubuntu switches to systemd, through.

Comment: What exactly this command do? Update: nevermind I checked the documentation